# Rails 6: Uncaught Reference Error - $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to get a semantic UI button to work using Javascript in Rails 6.  However, none of my code is working properly.  The code looks like this:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
   $('.message .close').on('click', function() {
   $(this).closest('.message').transition('fade');
   })
;
})
```

The error I'm getting is: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

My application JS file looks like:

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.
// Loads all Semantic javascripts
//= require jquery
//= require semantic-ui
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

This error references that $ is not declared yet which eventually denotes that jquery is not loaded into the page properly

check whether jquery gem is added in the gemfile or not

Also, try whether using `jQuery` as identifier instead of `$`

Comment: jquery is in the gemfile!  using jQuery responds with the same error, substituting $ with jQuery:/

Comment: apologies for giving late reply. if your issue not solved yet, then if u could post the snippets or screenshots of the following, u can get better help. 1, gemfile 2, application.js 3, main layout erb file with header 4, file with jquery snippet used 5, console log

Answer (score -1):

Add jquery supporting file in your html page.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This removes things out of the Webpacker environment and doesn't really solve the question asked.